# AngularJS bind on key press

Tags: html, angularjs, svg

Im developing a SVG application with AngularJS. We need a few modifications to fully support our internal browser, but it seems to be working.

See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/Thc44/

```
function Ctrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.tst = "iniValue";
    $scope.obj = { value : "iniValue2"};

    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("keyDown", event.keyCode);
        $scope.keyCode = event.keyCode;
    };

    $scope.keyHandler = function(event, keyCode) {
        $scope.tst = keyCode;
        $scope.obj = { value : keyCode};
        // $scope.$digest();
    };

    $scope.$on("keyDown", $scope.keyHandler);
}
```

Im trying to update some values in the HTML by the keypress event.
Im not able to use ng-keyup because its not supported by our browser or SVG document.

If we use the **$scope.$digest()** approach, everything works, but it seems that we lose a lot of performance.
$scope.apply() is even worst. It seems to refresh every node in the document. Not only the current controller.

I've tried every approach that I found only (method, object, ...) but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using the broadcast to send the event. It seems like unnecessary overhead. If you need to communicate to all of the scopes, you can just set the key code to the `$rootScope` like this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        $rootScope.keyCode = event.keyCode;
    });
};
```

This is automatically inherited by the child scopes and then instead of listening to a broadcast and forcing a digest across all of your document nodes, it only triggers the listeners for the key code. You can listen for changes using `$watch` like this:

```
$scope.$watch('keyCode', function () {
    if ($scope.keyCode) {
        $scope.tst = $scope.keyCode;
        $scope.obj = { value : $scope.keyCode};       
    }
});
```

That should perform better than the broadcast approach. This is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/P8987/

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I really like this approach, but take a look at this modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4DSz/ Its your version but with 2 controllers, even with the Ctrl2 not watching the keyCode it still execute the tst2() again. This is where we lose performance. We have a lot of calculations and verifications inside those functions.

Comment: You'll always get multiple cycles because once the model is mutated it has to walk again. You can improve your fiddle by removing the call to $scope.digest() (not needed with the $apply) and changing the watch code to detect only changes: `if ($scope.keyCode && (oldvalue !== newValue)) {` that produces far fewer cycles

Comment: The $scope.digest() was just trash left while doing some changes. Even detecting only changes, we will have poor performance as the current system is loaded into one single file, we change the view like a View Stack. This way every view will reloading the model even without a change. Thats why we use the digest approach to only reload the current controller that captured the event. I dont know if is there a better approach to apply only local changes.